# Getting a local IP from ISP router when behind NAT

Tags: networking, macos, ip, nat

I want my PC to have a unique IP on the LAN (192.168.1.x), however the PC does not have the capability to the router directly.

My current setup involves an ISP modem/router (1.254), a Mac (1.231, 2.1), and a PC (2.2) configured using the built-in MacOS Internet Sharing feature:

[image: Network configuration]

As far as I am aware, MacOS has no option to give the PC a unique IP on the LAN, so how can I go about doing this without purchasing more equipment? The Mac is able to run virtual machines, but they cannot impede internet functionality of the Mac.

Comment: You can't... Why not just get a cheap USB WiFi dongle for the Windows PC, you can get one for under $10, or a really good one for about $30, or even a PCIe internal one (if desktop)

Comment: Why does your PC not have the ability to connect to the ISP router directly?  (I can posit different scenarios which require different solutions.

Comment: Why do you feel the need for using the mac as a router? Why are you not just connecting the pc to the router either via wifi or ethernet?.

Comment: The Mac is positioned in a way where it's superior antenna will get a good signal from the router. The PC is located a few meters back behind a wall, where even with a dedicated Wi-Fi card (both PCI and USB were attempted), the signal is patchy at best. 
Similarly, a powerline adapter suffers from low speeds (5Mbps). 

The solution in mind was what a VM hypervisor does: allow individual VMs to get their on IP on the LAN. I have a VM running on the Mac using VirtualBox that has this exact setup and receives it's on unique IP, which leads me to believe something is possible for the PC.

Comment: You have still not said why you cannot run an ethernet cable.